# Merging Multiple Files Using Stax Parse Not Working

Tags: java, xml, java-8, stax

We are using the Java 8 and XML Stream API of Java to merge two xmls in a single threaded application.

Below are the two sample input xmls which I am trying to merge to the final xml. In both below sample xml html_tabs is common
element so in the final XML there must be only one html_tabs element.

```
Sample XML 1
-----------------------
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html_tabs lastRefreshDataDate="">
    <tab code="H_test_1" companyCode="H_test_1"
        id="H_test_1">
        <table>
            <tr><td>testing1 template</td></tr>
        </table>    
    </tab>  
</html_tabs>

Sample XML2
-----------------------
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html_tabs lastRefreshDataDate="">
    <tab code="H_test_2" companyCode="H_test_2"
        id="H_test_2">
        <table>
            <tr><td>testing2 template</td></tr>
        </table>    
    </tab>  
</html_tabs>

Merged XML
---------------
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<html_tabs lastRefreshDataDate="">
 <tab code="H_test_1" companyCode="H_test_1"
        id="H_test_1">
        <table>
            <tr><td>testing1 template</td></tr>
        </table>    
 </tab>
 <tab code="H_test_2" companyCode="H_test_2"
        id="H_test_2">
        <table>
            <tr><td>testing2 template</td></tr>
        </table>    
 </tab> 
</html_tabs>
```

Below is the code using which I am trying to merge two xml's by skipping the html_tabs element. I have skipped the import statement to keep the question short.

```
public class MergeXML1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLEventWriter eventWriter;
        XMLEventFactory eventFactory;
        XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        
        eventWriter = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream("testMerge1.xml"));
        eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
    
        // Create and write Start Tag
        XMLEvent statAbEvent = eventFactory.createStartDocument();
        eventWriter.add(statAbEvent);
        statAbEvent = eventFactory.createStartElement(StringUtils.EMPTY, StringUtils.EMPTY, "html_tabs");
        eventWriter.add(statAbEvent);
        statAbEvent = eventFactory.createAttribute("lastRefreshDataDate", StringUtils.EMPTY);
        eventWriter.add(statAbEvent);
        String[] filenames = new String[]{"4102530_1_statabfinsum.xml","4102530_2_statabfinsum.xml"};
        
        for (String filename : filenames) {
            XMLEventReader test = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(filename, new FileInputStream(filename));
            System.out.println("read the first file : " + filename);
            
            while (test.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = test.nextEvent();

                if (event.getEventType() != XMLEvent.START_DOCUMENT && event.getEventType() != XMLEvent.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (event.isStartElement()) {
                        StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
                        System.out.println("element name:" + startElement.getName().getLocalPart());
                        
                        if (!startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("html_tabs")) {
                            eventWriter.add(event);
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    eventWriter.add(event);
                }
            }
            
            test.close();
        }
        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndElement("", "", "html_tabs"));
        eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createEndDocument());
        eventWriter.close();

    }

}
```

Using above source code when am trying to merge two files it is throwing exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to output second root, <tab>
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1589)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1596)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1624)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.checkStartElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:483)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.SimpleNsStreamWriter.writeStartOrEmpty(SimpleNsStreamWriter.java:257)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.writeStartElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2EventWriterImpl.add(Stax2EventWriterImpl.java:100)
    at com.citi.research.distribution.tasks.downloadtasks.MergeXML1.main(MergeXML1.java:60)
```

I am not able to find out what is wrong with above code due to which the exception is coming.

Comment: _"Trying to output second root"_ says exactly what is happening. You are trying to output a second node at root level, i.e. you are not inside the root element when you are trying to write a node.  You are trying to output a node at the wrong level.

Comment: @jim garrison Thank you for quick reply. I need your help what I need to change in above code to make this work.

Comment: You need to do some step by step debugging to understand where you are going wrong.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks you for suggestion. But I have already tried to debug through code and found that when I am trying to insert the child nodes from second input XML file it is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on examining your code, it appears you copied the final `EndElement` from the first file to the output, putting you back at the top level. When you then tried to write the (correct) `StartElement` from the second file, you were trying to insert this at root level.

Filter out (i.e. do not write) the `EndElement` from the first file.

Comment: @JimGarrision In the source code I have already included the code not to include the start and end of document to first file and in input xml file last element is </html_tabs> which I am aready filtering it out. so what in above code I am missing. Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: sorry for confusion. I am able to figure out what you are trying to say in in the answer and I have fixed the code and it looks to me working fine. Thanks for help and apologies for the confusion I cause.

Comment: No problem.  I hope that my general direction (as opposed to just writing the code fix) provided a chance to learn for the future.